# NHibernate - QBE

Tags: nhibernate

I have a problem using QBE with NHibernate. I have a one-to-one relationship between a Person class and an Employee.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual string Forename { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual int PersonID { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public virtual int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual string PayRollNo { get; set; }
    public virtual int Holidays { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

As an example, I want to get all Employees where Employee.Forename="John" and Employee.Person.PayRollNo = "231A". I was wondering if I could use Query By Example to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to find a definitive "no" but I haven't been able to get this work. I've found that QBE is promising but unfortunately not very useful due to the following limitations:

- Cannot query related objects.
- Requires public parameterless constructor.
- Initialized properties are included in query unless specifically excluded using ExcludeProeprty. For example, bool properties are restricted to false in the where clause, DateTime as DateTime.MinValue. This makes the query very brittle because class modifications may have bad side effects.